# Carrierwave: clean CSV before upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, csv, carrierwave

I have a Carrierwave uploader `InventoryUploader` which I'm using to store files of format `text/csv` or `application/vnd.ms-excel`. I have been getting some invalid byte sequence errors when processing the files, so I would like to clean them out before uploading.

I've created a `process :clean_file` callback on the Carrierwave uploader but am struggling to find a good way to clean out any BOM / funky characters prior to upload.

Is there a neat way to do this? I'm trying with something like:

```rb
class InventoryUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
  end  

  def content_type_whitelist
    %w(text/csv application/vnd.ms-excel)
  end

  process :clean_file

  private

  def clean_file
    # Perhaps something like this?
    # but how can I ensure it removes all weird
    # character sequences?
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, encoding: 'UTF-8') do |row|
      row.each do |field|
        field[1].gsub!("\xEF\xBB\xBF".force_encoding("UTF-8"), '')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to do it with the following code:

```rb
require 'tempfile'

class InventoryUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def content_type_whitelist
    %w(text/csv application/vnd.ms-excel)
  end

  process :clean_file

  private

  def clean_file
    tempfile = Tempfile.open('temp_csv', encoding: 'utf-8') do |f|
      File.foreach(current_path) do |line|
        f.puts line.encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace)
      end
      f
    end
    FileUtils.mv(tempfile.path, current_path)
  end
end
```